# How to conditionally format a range of cells, based on a cells value, where that value is a specific formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with columns A through S, and roughly 200 rows. In column A I have several cells that contain different formulas. I want to conditionally format the entire row (A-S) based on a specific formula, such as `=first_inspection_name&" Inspection"`, found in column A.

I have tried formatting based on cell value, but that will only format the cell in column A.

I have also tried formatting based on a formula, like this: `=$A3="=first_inspection_name&" Inspection""` but I get an error.

I don't think I can name the cell because I sort the columns, and I'm not even sure how to format based on a named cell, it was just a thought.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `=$A3=first_inspection_name&" Inspection"` Use the formula not a string of the fomula.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Thank you. Please add that as an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just equate the formula to the cell:

```
=$A3=first_inspection_name&" Inspection"
```

and not the literal string of the formula.